# Making a Django web app work with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, web-applications, gunicorn, production

I am interesting in putting nginx and gunicorn in front ob of the following Django web app (https://github.com/fiduswriter/fiduswriter). This web abd runs fine with the usual `python manage.py runserver` command, but for gunicorn I would need to have the wsgi.py file, which I cannot find anywhere.

When inserting the code

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fiduswriter.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

into as fiduswriter/base/wsgi.py and running gunicorn as `gunicorn base.wsgi`I get the following error

```I am interesting in putting nginx and gunicorn in front ob of the following Django web app (https://github.com/fiduswriter/fiduswriter). This web abd runs fine with the usual `python manage.py runserver` command, but for gunicorn I would need to have the wsgi.py file, which I cannot find anywhere.

When inserting the code

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fiduswriter.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

into as fiduswriter/base/wsgi.py and running gunicorn as `gunicorn base.wsgi`I get the following error

```
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86714] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (86714)
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86714] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86716] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 86716
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86716] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/Dokumente/TextPrediction/fiduswriter/fiduswriter/base/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/fiduswriter/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fiduswriter'
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86716] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 86716)
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86714] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-07-26 14:36:16 +0200] [86714] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Therefore, I ask myself whether there is any way to bypass that issue for using gunicorn here.

Comment: Bypass what 'issue'?
file exists at `<project_name>/wsgi.py`

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot find it in the aforementioned Django web appb repo. This is why I am asking how to make this web app work  with gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you create Django project, wsgi.py automatically gets created, if it is missing you can create that file and copy code from internet, and I don't think there will be any way of using gunicorn without wsgi.py file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is there anything else I am supposed to insert apart form the standard text like https://github.com/microsoft/project-python-django-webapp/blob/master/python_webapp_django/wsgi.py ?

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work out. I explained my approach in the actual question a bit more detailed.

Comment: That's is issue with path, already answer are there on stackoverflow, please search it

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. However, I have been trying many things: Butting in some base directory (where most such code resides), in a newly formed directory called fiduswriter and much more. Still I got a "module not found" error. Do you know how to fix that?